# MacOS Sierra - Override PHP with XAMPP breaking brew

Tags: php, macos, terminal, homebrew, bash

I am wanting to forget about the built-in version of PHP that is on the mac and have the terminal use my XAMP version. I am getting different results from my browser vs CLI.

I edited my PATH in the `~/.bash_profile` which fixed my PHP version problem. However, it broke homebrew :(

---

bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH"
```

paths:

```
which php
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php

which brew
/usr/local/bin/brew

which head
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/head
```

This is causing brew to give me the list of commands no matter what I try.

```
 brew -v
 Unknown option: n
 Unknown option: 1
 ... list of command help...
```

Do I need to do something different with my `.bash_profile`? Maybe just alias php to the XAMPP?

Comment: Why are you doing this if you have Homebrew? `brew install php` and you're done.

Comment: Homebrew is finicky and I don't want php managed by it.

Comment: Ok I use macports so I'm not familiar with brew. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

What I did to get rid of this problem was I created a new bin folder (bin-osx) for php and mysql binaries and exported this new folder in .bash_profile.

```
$ cd /Applications/XAMPP/
$ mkdir bin-osx
$ cd bin-osx
```

I created links of php binaries inside bin-osx folder:

```
$ ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php* .
```

Since I needed mysql binaries too, I created mysql binaries links:

```
$ ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql* .
```

Edit your .bash_profile, make sure you have this contents (include other paths as well depending on your needs):

```
export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/bin-osx:$PATH"
```

Quit the terminal, then open it again - test it:

```
$ which php
/Applications/XAMPP/bin-osx/php

$ which mysql
/Applications/XAMPP/bin-osx/mysql

$ which head
/usr/bin/head
```

Finally, test "brew" command:

```
$ brew -v
Homebrew 1.2.4
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision e08d; last commit 2017-07-16)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: brew doctor complains about the php-config it finds in /Applications/XAMPP/bin-osx but otherwise this fixes up my issues.

Comment: I just ran brew doctor, and yes, I saw this too. I removed /Applications/XAMPP/bin-osx/php-config symlink. Then the error is now gone.